# Handle outbound proxy in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, proxy, asp.net-core-middleware

I am migrating the asp.net web application to asp.net core 6.0. For handling inbound proxies i have followed the following Microsoft link;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0

**Is there any link or guideline for managing outbound proxy?**

I have tried this so far but not sure if this is a right way of managing outbound proxy.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient("SampleClient", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sample.client.url.com");
            })
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy("https://sample.proxy.url.com")
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows server, you could also use the environment variable to set the proxy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\testapplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="http_proxy" value="proxyip"/>
          <environmentVariable name="https_proxy" value="proxyip"/>
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```